# Printing a singly list like an array, problem is last comma still stays when I don't want it to

Tags: python, python-3.x, singly-linked-list

```
    def printList(self):
        node=self.head
        #check if list is empty (when there is no head element)
        if self.head is None:
            print("Empty List")
            return
        
        #prints list if not empty
        print("[",end="")
        while node is not None:
            print(node.val, end=",")
            node = node.next
        print("]")
```

This is what I have so far, and the output I get is

```
[A,A,B,]
```

Just wondering if there is a simpler way of just getting rid of the last character

I cant put an answer but I just did it

```
            if node.next is None:
                print(node.val, end="")
```

Comment: The linked answer requires creating a list in duplication of the whole structure (which may not be desirable).  What you could do in your code is to initialize a separator variable before the loop like `comma=""`, print it *before* you print each value `print(comma,end="")` and assign it to your actual separator after the printing it `comma=","`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I can think is using a `list` to store the data and forming a `str` out of it using `join`

Example:

```
#using join
my_list = []
for i in range(10):
    my_list.append(i)
my_str = ', '.join(str(j) for j in my_list)
print(my_str)
print(f'[{my_str}]')
```

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to turn a list of string to one string, use join:

```
",".join(something_iterable)
```

For example:

```py
>>> this_is_a_list = [ "AA", "BB", "CC" ]
>>> print(",".join(this_is_a_list))
AA,BB,CC
```